# Semantic UI Grid Column not adapting height

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-css

Im trying out semantic UI. I want to make some admin Panel cards with stats but I have the problem, that if I change the font size of the number inside the column, it overflows the segment...
Same with cards.

This is my html:

```html
<div class="ui grid container">
  <div class="four wide column">
    <div class="ui segment">
      <div class="ui container stat-number">12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Css which belongs to the html:

```css
.stat-number {
  font-size: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.stat-icon {
  float: left;
}
```

And this is the result:
[image]

Comment: It seems that floating the `.stat-number` removes it from the normal document flow, so it doesn't contribute any height to its parent.

Comment: okay you are right. If I remove the floating, it fits inside the segment. But what to to, if i want to have to divs side by side inside a segment?

Comment: What does the `.stat-icon` element look like?

Comment: Normally it should be floated but as we can see it can‘t.. there will be an fontawesome svg inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution might be to use the ["clearing" class](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/segment.html#clearing).

```css
.stat-number {
  font-size: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.stat-icon {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ui grid container">
  <div class="four wide column">
    <div class="ui segment clearing">
      <div class="stat-number">12</div>
      <div class="stat-icon">*</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am no expert in Semantic UI.
There might be a more appropriate way to float elements with classes.